# Proof of symmetry for trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

How can I algebraically prove this trigonometric symmetry for sin?

$\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$

Comment: The angle $-\theta$ is the angle $\theta$ reflected through the $x$-axis. (I assume you're using "right-angle trig".)

Comment: What level are you working at? If you know series, think about the series representation of the functions.

Comment: Yes, but can we prove this algebraically?

Comment: It drops out of applying the difference law to $\sin(0-x)$. (I don't recall if the difference law uses this fact in its proof, though.)

Comment: Define "algebraically prove". Using $\sin x=\sum\cdots$ is OK?

Comment: It depends on how you *define* the sine in the first place. That identity might well be by definition, for instance, if you define sines geometrically.

Comment: Are you fine with assuming $\cos$ is even? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go from the definition of $sin(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

From there, factor $-x$ into $(-1)x$ and use $(xy)^a = x^ay^a$

Notice since $n$ is an integer you can say that $(-1)^{2n+1} = (-1)^{1}= -1$

Comment: You dropped the $-$ sign in the definition

Comment: Edited to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use complex numbers and Euler's formula, try this algebraic argument:

Let $z= e^{ix} = \cos x+i\,\sin x$. Then 
$$
e^{-ix} = \frac1z = \frac{\bar z}{z\bar z} = \frac{\cos x - i \sin x}{\cos^2 + \sin^2x} = \cos x - i \sin x
$$

On the other hand,
$$
e^{-ix} = \cos(-x)+i\,\sin(-x)
$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts we get
$$
\cos(-x) = \cos(x) 
\qquad
\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)
$$

Comment: A question: Is it legitimate to use $\cos{x}-i \sin{x} = \overline{e^{ix}}=e^{-ix}$ instead of using the inversion you did?

Comment: @Dror, how do you prove that $\overline{e^{ix}}=e^{-ix}$ ?

Comment: $|e^{ix}|^2=1=e^0=e^{ix}e^{-ix} \implies \overline{e^{ix}}=e^{-ix}$

Comment: If more justification is required for this implication, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653083/complex-number-congjugate-criteria/653097#653097).